# How to implement tensorflow Object detection api with own model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

i working with tensorflow object detection api, i want use my own model with 30 classes created similar to mnist network. I haven't idea how to do that because in every tutorial recommend using pretrained model. I even create my pb file and all .meta file, and i used it to object detection api. When i run script on my own images a get errors like

```
detection_boxes:0 is not recognized tensor ,
```

I now that in my graph i don't have this tensors but i dont known how to modify my model, can i use tensorflow object detection api using my own model with no labeled images?